# How to Change abscissa of the angular 6 line -chart

Tags: angular

[image: Output Picture]I'm using this chart code https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts into my project all looks good but i need to move abscissa  of horizontal x-axis label points(jan,feb,march etc) to up instead of below . Can anyone help me, Thanks

Comment: it seems it is not possible. possition of these labels aren't configurable. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/

Comment: hi @Andrei then may i get any other angular line-charts link examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change x-axis location by adding following options to lineChartOptions

```
{
    scales: { 
      xAxes: [{ position: 'top'}]},
    responsive: true,
};
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-line-template-mlcsrc?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Unfortunately it is hard to do customization in ng2-charts or chart.js,

So I would like to suggest you to use d3 (data driven documents), Using d3 you will able to create any graph as you want.

I have changed abscissa, Here is the link to solution

https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-line-chart-k3cu8q?embed=1&file=src/app/bar-chart.ts

You can customize it as you need for more details you can visit [d3](https://d3js.org/).

Comment: Hi @abhijeet-abnave Thanks, But the X-axis label points(Jan,Feb,March) should come **Top** not at bottom [https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsutP.png]

Comment: Hi @shivu It was little confusing, but thanks for edit and letting me know, I have made changes in stackblitz. Just check it again.

Comment: HI can any one help us [ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60769882/change-abscissa-of-all-points-on-x-axis-in-angular-google-charts ]